# How to include a file into your project

Tags: google-apps-script, include

I'm creating a Google Apps Script that's kind of a quiz marker / email merger in one. I've got everything working but my code is pretty long because I find myself having to use procedural coding. This is mostly because I don't know how to use the editor to include a class / library.

I've viewed the Crash Course Video by Kalyan on using the Script Editor, but it didn't answer my question. I've also scoured the internet with no luck.

If you look in the top left of this screenshot, you'll see I have `Code.gs` and `test.gs`:

[image: screenshot]

I have all my code in the `Code.gs` file, but I want to include `test.gs` in `Code.gs`. Once I figure out how to do that, I'd like to create a couple of simple classes to organize my functions a bit better (and possibly re-use my classes later).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You already included the code. You dont need to do anything else.

Answer (score 26):

To clarify Zig Mandel's answer and add to it:

- All .gs files that are located in the same *Script Project* have global access to each other. That is to say that a function that you define in **test.gs** is accessible by **Code.gs** if they are in the same Script Project
- You can create your own *library* of code. To do this you would simply create another *Script Project*, then go to `Resources -> Manage libraries...`, and add the **project key** of your original project (that contains the Code.gs and test.gs files). The *project key* is located in `File -> Project properties`.

The second bullet point is a good way to organize your code. If you have the same code that you are reusing throughout many Script Projects, then you want to put those functions into one Script Project and create a *library* out of them, as I explained above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wanted to add that you can make the method calls exactly the same as you would from the original file.  For example `someFunction()`  instead of `Code.someFunction()`.

Answer (score 3):

You already included the code. Should work as is. You can also look at the apps script docummentation and learn to use libraries for code reuse:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries.

This makes development easier but for best performance you should include them all in your project  before publishing like you did this time.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the problem may be the order of execution.  The .gs files are executed in order of creation.  Copying Code.gs, deleting the original, then running functions from the new copy may fix your problem.

Comment: Deleting and recreating is unnecessary. You can use the context menu for each file to move it up and down, which determines the order in which the files are executed.

Comment: That wasn't true when I wrote this answer 3 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?!= include('JavaScript.html'); ?>


function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).